# When will postUserFunc executed

Tags: typo3

I create a typoscript file. In this file i include my own PHP file like:

```
includeLibs.sendNews = fileadmin/send_news.php
```

In my PHP file i have a function `execute`. Now i call the function execute with typoscript `postUserFunc`, but my function never executed.

```
page.stdWrap.postUserFunc = execute
```

I don't find in the documentation when was the `postUserFunc` executed. Can someone help me and give me a hint when was the postUserFunc executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TYPO3 6.2, the execution order of `stdWrap`-properties can be found in the [source code of the content object renderer, line 62ff](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/_content_object_renderer_8php_source.html#l00062).

The gist of the order is below, I have removed some things that occur double due to technicalities. As you can see, the `postUserFunc` is executed as almost the last thing.

```
    stdWrapPreProcess
    cacheRead
    setContentToCurrent
    addPageCacheTags
    setCurrent
    lang.
    data
    field
    current
    cObject
    numRows
    filelist
    preUserFunc
    stdWrapOverride
    override
    preIfEmptyListNum
    ifNull
    ifEmpty
    ifBlank
    listNum
    trim
    strPad
    stdWrap
    stdWrapProcess
    required
    if.
    fieldRequired
    csConv
    parseFunc
    HTMLparser
    split.
    replacement.
    prioriCalc
    char
    intval
    hash
    round
    numberFormat.
    expandList
    date
    strftime
    age
    case
    bytes
    substring
    removeBadHTML
    cropHTML
    stripHtml
    crop
    rawUrlEncode
    htmlSpecialChars
    encodeForJavaScriptValue
    doubleBrTag
    br
    brTag
    encapsLines.
    keywords
    innerWrap
    innerWrap2
    fontTag
    addParams.
    textStyle.
    tableStyle.
    filelink.
    preCObject
    postCObject
    wrapAlign
    typolink.
    TCAselectItem.
    space
    spaceBefore
    spaceAfter
    wrap
    noTrimWrap
    wrap2
    dataWrap
    prepend
    append
    wrap3
    orderedStdWrap
    outerWrap
    insertData
    offsetWrap
    postUserFunc
    postUserFuncInt
    prefixComment
    editIcons
    editPanel
    cacheStore
    stdWrapPostProcess
    debug
    debugFunc
    debugData
```

Comment: My function which was triggered by posUserFunc select users from tt_address and send this users email. After sending a email the user record was updated with a flag that a email was send. But the users receive always two emails that was the reason of my question so i can debug why this issue happen.